# How to recover files from macOS after accidentally overwriting it with Linux>

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

*I'm not a kid (this is an alt account with a different email. I forgot the other password of @adamgewely)*

But I accidentally replaced macOS with Linux! I had important files there. Thinking it was on external 16GB hard drive, I was planning on replacing it with Linux, but not this fast!

I tried booting to an external drive, ut it didn't work.

Can I find a way to recover macOS (I only need the documents folder But recovering as much as possible is also very good.)

I've just did this mistake 1 hour ago when this question was posted.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: First, **stop using the computer** to reduce changes of destroying more data. Second, **boot from USB using recovery tools** and make an image of the disk as it is now. Third, once you have an image safely stored, try some of the recovery tools to get back data: https://iboysoft.com/mac-data-recovery/file-recovery-software-mac.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com//help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.